# Google Postmaster Domain Reputation - which header is the source of tracked domain?

Tags: smtp, email-headers, massmail, google-postmaster

In my message's header I have two different domains used:

- in Received - there is mta.abc.domain.com
- in From - address belongs to def.domain.com
  Which domain's reputation will be tracked in Google Postmaster: abc.domain.com or def.domain.com?

It is hard to test it because Google Postmaster requires quite large volume of sends.

Thank you!